# SubViews disappear in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Ok so this is really weird. I don't use interface builder anymore because of all of it's quirks like this one, but I am working on an old project I did. When I go to interface builder all of the Subviews are not visible, and they're opaque in the document outline. See photo below.

[image]

When the app runs, it works fine. There is also a problem when compressing the project to a zip file, an error occurs. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check size class here,I think that your old project is build for a size class and you view it on another

[image]